# Firebase Cloud Function called twice onCreate

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have this function:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/my_node/{myId}/status').onCreate(event => {
  const data = event.data.val();
  if (data == 'STATE01') {
    return event.data.ref.set('STATE02');
  }
});
```

I am using `onCreate`, it should be called once only. But it has called 2 times

> 9:29:27.975 PM myFunction Function execution took 33 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
>
> 9:29:27.943 PM myFunction Function execution started
>
> 9:29:27.875 PM myFunction Function execution took 1059 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
>
> 9:29:26.818 PM myFunction Function execution started

Comment: What did you do to trigger the function?  Maybe add some logging of the data to better illustrate what's happening here, other than it being called twice?

Comment: Tanks, the function is called automatically by Firebase when a node with this hierarchy `/my_node/{myId}/status` is created. I test with more logs.